# Using Previous Result to Run Recursive Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, recursion

I am trying to write a Javascript recursive function to help with calculations on another project, and I'm running into issues when trying to write out the function and get it to work as intended. I know some Javascript, but I'm no expert, so apologies if there may be some bad practices in my code. I have a function called `quadraticSequencer` that takes in an argument, `num`, and generates a quadratic sequence up to the given input num. It then returns the final output to be used and passed into the following function, `subtraction`. This is where the first issue occurs and the logic doesn't run as intended... ( where it should just return the last output in the sequence and pass it into the `subtraction` function, it seems to pass only the first output only and stops. )

The `subtraction` function takes in two arguments, `num` and `nthTerm` (which was returned and passed in from the `quadraticSequencer` function ), and runs a recursive function that redefines `nthTerm` as `level` and takes the `level` and subtracts it from `num` to generate a `result`, or `const result = num - level`. An if / else statement runs to check the result for divisibility using the modulo % operator, and if passes it console.logs `result`. If failed it moves to the next `level` (or iterative step down) and subtracts that from the PREVIOUS `result` and NOT `num`. That last part is critical because I'm not sure how to execute this logic correctly so that the previous `result` is stored for the next subtraction.

i.e. if num = 75, `nthTerm` would be 11, and the `subtraction` function would subtract 75 like so:

75 - 11. result = 64 || 64 - 10. result = 54 || 54 - 9. result = 45 || 45 - 8. result = 37 || 37 - 7. result = 30 || 30 - 6. result = 24 || 24 - 5. result = 19 || 19 - 4. result = 15 || 15 - 3. result = 12 || 12 - 2. result = 10 || 10 - 1. result = 9.

Hopefully, that makes sense. This is just how the subtraction has to run for our calculations to be accurate. If the first run-through finishes, it also does a "double-run" and adds more subtractions, basically subtracting in reverse and adding on more subtractions, not removing subtractions. So a full run with no passes would look like this: 75-11-10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11. Checking every `result` per subtraction. I wasn't sure how to write this within the if / else statement.

The overall expected output is to get the last output from the `quadtraticSequencer` function to pass it into the `subtraction` function for calculations, and the `subtraction` function be able to run as intended. So when `num = 75`, the `subtraction` function should pass when the `level` or "step" is 4 and the `result` = 15, or 75-11-10-9-8-7-6-5-4 = 15. 75 % 15 = 0. // 15

Here's my code:

```
const num = 75;

function quadraticSequencer(num) {
  // initialize with zero but you can remove the value here
  nthTermArr = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    // generates quadratic sequence.
    let a = i;
    let b = 1 / 2;
    nthTerm = a;
    quadraticSequence = b * a ** 2 + b * a;

    if (quadraticSequence <= num) {
      nthTermArr.push(nthTerm);
    } else {
      false;
    }
  }

  let level = nthTermArr.slice(-1).pop();
  console.log(level);

  function subtraction(num, level) {
    let result = num - level;
    console.log(result);

    if (num % result === 0) {
      console.log(result);
    } else if (num % result !== 0) {
      return subtraction(result, level - 1);
    } else {
      false;
    }
  }
  console.log(subtraction(num, level));
}

quadraticSequencer(num);
```

The wanted result for the `quadraticSequencer` function is to output results that meet the if / else statements within the `subtraction` function. If there are no passes, then there is no output.

Comment: please add the exact wanted result of your two functions. btw, you can not retur two values separated with comma. the last value wins. for returning more than one value, you need an array or object or other data structures.

Comment: Functions only return a single value, `return quadraticSequence, nthTerm;` will only return *nthTerm*. If you want to return multiple values, they must be in an array or object like `return [quadraticSequence, nthTerm]` or `return {quadraticSequence: somdValue, nthTerm: anotherValue}`.

Comment: @RobG Understood, I updated the post as well, the subtraction function still doesn't seem to run correctly still. I'm still working on it though.

Comment: I edited my original answer to include some more code, see below

Comment: As Nina asked, please include the expected output for some sample inputs.  It's not clear to me if your initial input is simply, say `75`, and if so what result you want from the function.  Is it something like `[75, 64, 54, 45, 37, 30, 24, 19, 15]` ?  And if so, do we simply stop when our result is a factor of `75`?  Or if this isn't it, what is your output?

Comment: @ScottSauyet You are exactly correct! That's the output and the result I'm looking for. To stop when we hit a factor or we're at 1. I also updated my code because I figured out how to get my nthTerm but now I'm not sure how to handle the subtraction logic.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I think I got the code to a good state, its somewhat running now but the subtraction isn't subtracting like intended. Could you help me out?

Comment: @King Muze: Added an answer.  It might be what you want, but I haven't tried to work out what's wrong with your code.  Mine is a very different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying way too hard.  A little algebra here will take you a long way and give you a solution like this:

```js
const max = (n) => 
  Math.floor ((-1 + Math.sqrt (1 + 8 * n)) / 2)

const quadraticSequence = (n, c = n, t = max (c)) =>
  [c, ... (c > 1 && (c == n || n % c != 0) ? quadraticSequence (n, c - t) : [])]

console .log ('75: ', ... quadraticSequence (75))
console .log ('74: ', ... quadraticSequence (74))
console .log ('73: ', ... quadraticSequence (73))
console .log ('72: ', ... quadraticSequence (72))
console .log ('71: ', ... quadraticSequence (71))
console .log ('70: ', ... quadraticSequence (70))
```

Here we use `max` to find the highest value `k` such that 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + k is no bigger than our target.  Then our main function recursively calls that after subtracting it from the current value.

The derivation for `max` is simply to recognize that the sum of the first `k` positive integers is `k * (k + 1) / 2`.  If we want to find the maximum where this is less than `n`, we have the inequality:

```
k * (k + 1) / 2 <= n
```

which we can rearrange to get

```
k ** 2 + k - 2 * n  <= 0,
```

and using the quadratic formula (knowing that everything is positive here) to find

```
k <= ((-1 + sqrt (1 - 4 * (1) * (-2n))) /2)
```

and so we end up with

```
floor ((-1 + sqrt (1 + 8 * n)) / 2)
```

The main function accepts your target number, `n`, copies it to a current value, `c`, and calculates that top value, `t` using the above.  We include `c` in our output and then check our original `n` and current `c` to see if we should recur.  We stop when c <= 1, or when our original is a multiple of our current value (except when they're equal, the first time around.  When we do recur, we pass the same original value and the difference between our current value and that calculated maximum.

Comment: Oh sweet! This works great and it's so clean! How could I also add on to this in a way in which I could add another case other than != so I could perform a quick multiplication on c and check n % c? Sometimes c is a decimal that we need, so we have to add a bit more logic to check for certain cases. Then it's golden!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow your follow-up.  But perhaps you should play around a bit and if you can't get it to work, ask another question.

Comment: Sorry, I should've provided more context. For example, a result could be a decimal such as 2.5 or 8.4. So in the case of num = 75, when we get to the result 30, 75 / 30 = 2.5. I must take the 2.5 and multiply it by 10 to bring it up to a whole number. If it's something like, 8.4, I need to multiply it by 5 to bring it up to a whole number. Once it's a whole number, I must then take that number and n % c it and check for divisibility. I'm playing with your solution, but it's a bit hard to see where I could place the logic. Does this make sense?

Comment: Not to me, but I won't have any time to look more closely at this for many hours, and likely not before tomorrow.

Comment: Gotcha! Will ask another question, thanks for the solution!! I really appreciate the execution!

Answer (score 1):

take your variables out of the loop

```
function quadraticSequencer(num) {
  // initialize with zero but you can remove the value here
  let [nthTerm, quadraticSequence] = [0, 0]
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    // generates quadratic sequence.
    let a = i;
    let b = 1 / 2;
    nthTerm = a - 1;
    quadraticSequence = b * a ** 2 + b * a;

  if (quadraticSequence <= num) {
    return nthTerm;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
```

}

You can then get the values by using

```
const result = quadraticSequencer(num);
if(!result) {
  // function returned false, there is no result
}
else { 
  // if there is a result
  
}
```

Comment: I added in your solution, could you take a look at my subtraction function to see why that may not be running as intended? I don't see any errors in my console but I'm also not getting any hits on the if / else statement..

Comment: First your substraction function should not be in your quadraticSequence function
Second your never call the substraction function

Comment: Right, that's what I figured, but then I seem to lose access to the nthTerm variable. Even if I try and pass it into the call after I call the sequencer function, it throws an error saying it's undefined or I get a scope error.

Comment: I'm still working on it and seeing what to adjust and move, just a bit mentally exhausted so apologies if I may seem like I'm not getting something.

Comment: There's a missing bracket to close the *for* loop block before the *if..else* block.

Comment: You assign the result of quadraticSequencer without checking if there is an actual result, you might need to add if else like in my code to address that issue.

Comment: @Zerowiel I made the tweaks but still not getting a result back... Were you able to get a result on your end with the solution provided? I know it's not a syntax error because I'm not getting any errors in console or editor.

Comment: It's something funky with that return in the quadtraticSequencer function, it's not given the correct return. When I use console.log, I see the output, but it's like the return only wants to stop at the first iteration which is not what I need. The last iteration, where the condition finally stops, is what I need.

Comment: A lot of things are wrong in your code, i would advise you to rewrite it step by step. We can't solve the whole problem for you :/
For exemple : quadraticSequencer(100) return 0 is that expected ? You are trying to assign result to result - level without using =, you are using previousResult without declaring it, etc... Maybe you should try to write pseudo code and edit your answer to provide it.

Comment: I think I got the code to a good state, its somewhat running now but the subtraction isn't subtracting like intended,